# How to stop sort_values sorting by column names alphabetically?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sorting, dataframe

I am working with a pandas dataframe, in which some of the columns have no entries. I want to put all columns at the end and I manage to do it (see code below), but I also notice that after sorting the remaining columns were also sorted alphabetically by column names in descending order. Can I prevent this from happening?

Input dataframe:

```
,colA,colB,colC,colD,colF
rowA,X,nan,nan,X,nan
rowB,nan,X,nan,nan,X
rowC,X,nan,nan,X,X
rowD,X,nan,nan,nan,nan
rowE,nan,X,nan,nan,X
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv (r'q1.csv', dtype= 'str', index_col=0, na_values = 'nan')
ind = df.notnull().astype('int').any().sort_values(ascending= False).index
out = df.loc[:,ind]
out.to_csv(r'out.csv', na_rep= 'nan')
```

Output dataframe:

```
,colF,colD,colB,colA,colC
rowA,nan,X,nan,X,nan
rowB,X,nan,X,nan,nan
rowC,X,X,nan,X,nan
rowD,nan,nan,nan,X,nan
rowE,X,nan,X,nan,nan
```

Essentially, I want to keep order as it is for all other columns.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you may try this.

```
m = df.isna().all().sort_values(kind='mergesort')
df_new = df[m.index]

Out[243]:
     colA colB colD colF  colC
rowA    X  NaN    X  NaN   NaN
rowB  NaN    X  NaN    X   NaN
rowC    X  NaN    X    X   NaN
rowD    X  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
rowE  NaN    X  NaN    X   NaN
```